# Removendo arquivos por período de tempo

Tags: powershell, sistema-de-arquivos

Estou com script para remover arquivo deixando somente os últimos definidos em dia

Script:

```
$Now = Get-Date
$Days = 30
$TargetFolder = "C:\LOG"
$Extension = "*.*"
$LastWrite = $Now.AddDays(-$Days)
$Files = Get-Childitem $TargetFolder -Include $Extension -Recurse | Where {$_.LastWriteTime -le "$LastWrite"}

foreach ($File in $Files)
        {
            if ($File -ne $NULL)
                {
                    write-host "Deletando arquivo $File" -ForegroundColor "DarkRed"
                    Remove-Item $File.FullName | out-null
                }
            else
                {
                    Write-Host "Nao ha arquivos a serem excluidos!" -foregroundcolor "Green"
                }
        }
```

Acontece que no meu computador (Windows 7 64bits) funciona perfeitamente já no servidor (Win2008 R2 64bits) apresenta o seguinte erro:

> Confirm The item at
>   Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::E:\LOG\Maplink.Service.Monitor.HourlyTasks
>   has children and the Recurse parameter was not specified. If you
>   continue, all children will be removed with the item. Are you sure you
>   wan to continue? [Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S]
>   Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):

Comment: É um erro ou uma mensagem de confirmação? 'respondendo' `Y` ou `A` ele remove os arquivos?

Comment: Para deixar de receber o pedido de confirmação, passe `-recurse` ao `Remove-Item`. No entanto convém verificar porque e que tem directórios nos ficheiros na colecção de ficheiros.

Comment: Ao confirmar Y alguns arquivos são deletados outros não, já simplifiquei o codigo para:

$Dir = "E:\LOG"
$Day = 30
$Date = (get-date) - (new-timespan -day $Day)

Get-ChildItem $Dir -recurse | where {$_.LastWriteTime -le $Date} | del

erro persiste.

Comment: Quando adiciono -recurse ao invés de Remove-Item apresenta o seguinte erro:

Missing Expression after unary operator '-'.
At D:\utilidade\cleanlog.ps1:21 char:7
+        - <<<<recurse $File.FullNamo | out-null
+ CategoryInfo    : ParseError: (-:String) [], Parse Exception

Comment: @JucimárioSantana relativamente ao erro, parece que o `-` nao esta a ser [reconhecido](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19600881/1242661). Ja experimentou usar `-force` para garantir que os ficheiros são eliminados?

Comment: Já sim e dá no mesmo erro.

Comment: O utilizador tem permissoes para eliminar esses ficheiros? Se correr a sessao de powershell como admin o erro continua?

Comment: Sim, quando eu coloco uma pasta especifica sem ter outra pasta dentro funciona normalmente.

Comment: Fiz um teste como `remove-item $File.Name -Recurse -force | out-null` na estrututa: `C:\log\pasta1\pasta2` ele apagou todos os arquivos porém manteu pasta1 e pasta2, nesse teste removi essa parta também `| Where {$_.LastWriteTime....`

Comment: Confirmo os resultados do @perdeu, testei em Win7 e Server2008 R2 e apagou como devia.

Comment: fiz o que informou e deu esse outro erro:

Remove-Item : Cannot find path 'D:\Utilidades\Task\v4.2' because it does not exist.
At D:\Utilidades\Task\CleanLog.ps1:21 char:17
+                     Remove-Item <<<<  $File.Name -Recurse -force | out-null
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (D:\Utilidades\Task\v4.2:String) [Remove-Item]
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand

Comment: @Omni, testei no win8 com arquivo ps1 já salvo. O prompt de confirmação não apareceu.

Comment: Consegui solucionar, estava faltando um parametro:
Solução substituindo o Where pelo script abaixo:
Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.LastWriteTime -le $Date}

Vlw Pessoal..

Comment: @JucimárioSantana, coloque isso como resposta e explique melhor, isso pode ajudar mais pessoas com o mesmo problema.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui solucionar, estava faltando um parâmetro: Solução substituindo o `Where` pelo script abaixo:

```
Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.LastWriteTime -le $Date}
```